# Does Ubuntu 13.04 work on HP Pavilion g7-2243us?

Tags: 13.04, hp

I have an "HP Pavilion g7-2243us 17.3" notebook running Windows 8. I was wondering if Ubuntu 13.04 installs and runs perfectly or if it won't work? Please help me, because I need to do this fast. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any answer you'll get for this will be a speculative one, such as mine.

There is no reason to believe that Ubuntu won't work on your laptop. If you have good reason to be worried, then it is best to do a "dual-boot" installation first and test it out.

Download the latest `.exe` installer from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer).

It will prompt you with options to install alongside windows as a dual-boot.

After installing, during the boot up of your computer, you will see a menu letting you choose to boot to Ubuntu or windows.